# Remove character from json string

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

i have this :

```
"{Table1: [{\"PropertyTaxReceiptAmt\":\"2200170.00\",\"WaterTaxReceiptAmt\":\"79265.00\"}]}"
```

i want output like

```
PropertyTaxReceiptAmt:2200170.00
WaterTaxReceiptAmt:79265.00
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. This is **not** how you ask questions here. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string json = "{Table1: [{\"PropertyTaxReceiptAmt\":\"2200170.00\",\"WaterTaxReceiptAmt\":\"79265.00\"}]}";
json = json.Replace("\\", string.Empty);
json = json.Trim('"');
json = json.Replace("{Table1:", string.Empty);
json = json.Remove(json.Length -1,1);
Console.Write(json);
```

Comment: Because of get only key parameter pair to deserialization this json string

Answer (score 1):

A much easier way to do the same thing as the accepted answer:

```
string json = "{Table1: [{\"PropertyTaxReceiptAmt\":\"2200170.00\",\"WaterTaxReceiptAmt\":\"79265.00\"}]}";

json = JObject.Parse(json)["Table1"].ToString();

Console.Write(json);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PLPEno